# Sollving problem with fullcalendar and angular 8

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm getting the next issue from the console with angular 8:

Module '"../../../../../../../../node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/fullcalendar-angular"' has no exported member 'CalendarOptions'.

In last versions it can be solved installing angular 3.6.1 but that was four years ago and it not should be the correct and also it doesn't works for my case, another solution is change to version 3.7.0, but it doesn't works, and the documentation of angular is bad, I'm using exactly the same code that the documentation ask for use it.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Another thing that I should let clear, the pluguin works, but if the console is throwing it to me is for some reason, so I want to know how to fix it.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "angular-ng-stepper": "^1.0.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng-sidebar": "^9.4.2",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^9.3.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

And this is my component.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { MainRoutingModule } from './main-routing.module';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { MyTasksComponent } from './components/myTasks/MyTasks.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/Dashboard.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './components/tasks/task.component';

//NgZorro
import { NzLayoutModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/layout';
import { NzIconModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/icon';
import { NzMenuModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/menu';
import { NzAvatarModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/avatar';
import { NzDropDownModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/dropdown';
import { NzButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/button';
import { NzModalModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/modal';
import { NzAffixModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/affix';
import { NzSelectModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/select';
import { NzCollapseModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/collapse';
import { NzGridModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/grid';
import { NzListModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/list';
import { NzCardModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/card';
import { NzSkeletonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/skeleton';
import { NzSwitchModule} from 'ng-zorro-antd/switch';
import { NzDrawerModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/drawer';
import { NzTabsModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/tabs';


// Angular Material
import { DragDropModule } from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

// Full Calendar
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'; // this plugin isn´t installed
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline';
import { ViewTasksComponent } from './components/viewtasks/viewtasks.component';


FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([ // register FullCalendar plugins
  dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timeGridPlugin, //resourceTimelinePlugin
]);

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  timeGridPlugin,
  listPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
]);


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    MyTasksComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    TaskComponent,
    ViewTasksComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NzListModule,
    FormsModule,
    MainRoutingModule,
    FullCalendarModule,
    NzLayoutModule,
    NzIconModule,
    NzMenuModule,
    NzCollapseModule,
    NzAvatarModule,
    NzButtonModule,
    NzDropDownModule,
    NzGridModule,
    NzModalModule,
    NzAffixModule,
    NzSelectModule,
    NzCardModule,
    NzSkeletonModule,
    NzSwitchModule,
    NzDrawerModule,
    NzTabsModule,
    DragDropModule
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

Comment: Can you edit to show app.module.ts?

Comment: sure, I added it @NathanToulbert

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the register the module in your app.module.ts as well. In your case, this looks like:

```
FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  timeGridPlugin,
  listPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
  resourceTimelinePlugin
])
```

Comment: I have the import, I add the module.ts, you can check

Comment: You need to also register plugins, or in other words, declare FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins like [this.](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/angular/src/app/app.module.ts) Notice the declarations below the imports (lines 10-15) let me know if it fixes so I can change answer pls.

Comment: I went ahead and added it as an answer.

Comment: I added it but the issue stay there, I updated the changes